# Is the Concorde Agreement still in effect?

Tags: formula-1

In Formula 1 the Concorde Agreement set forth a division of money from TV rights all the way to how much power individual teams had along with a special component for Ferrari where they could veto initiatives and no other team could.

How much of the Concord Agreement is still in effect?

I know Ferrari still has veto power but what about TV revenue and such as well as revenue from races, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell, yes it is still in force.

The Concorde Agreement was first signed back in 1981 but it has been renewed, with changes, seven times since then.  The current agreement was signed in 2013 and expires at the end of 2020.

For more details about the specifics you can read the Wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concorde_Agreement#Seventh_Concorde_Agreement_.282013.29